# Can one set idle rpm through a commercial OBD diagnostic tool?

Tags: obd-ii

I'm talking about "permanently" setting the engine's ECU to maintain an idle RPM of my choice, say, 1200 or 1500?  (by "permanently", I mean something that would be maintained after power cycling)

If yes, do I need a special OBD device?  (the basic ones only read and display diagnostic code).

What about connecting a kvaser to the OBD port, with a Linux laptop so that I can manually insert any message of my choice on the CAN  (would it be reasonably easy?)

Comment: What vehicle are we talking about?

Comment: @motosubatsu -- it's for a Nissan Versa 2008 (hatchback, 1.8SL).  Canadian model, in case there are any differences.

Comment: Why is the stock idle setting unsatisfactory? What else is going on with the vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it will depend on what vehicle you have.  All OBD2 vehicles operate within the same parameters, but each automaker uses those parameters differently.  Best bet, see if there's a 2 way data cable and PC-based software on the market for your vehicle.  Then see if idle speed adjustment is offered as one of the parameters.